# jbuilder view renders with layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have a controller that sometimes renders html and sometimes json.

For json I use jbuilder views.

There is a default html layout, that for some unknown reason start to get rendered also for the json view.

I found 2 options that fixes the issue

1. add `layout:false` to the render call with the json view
2. call render partial instead a regular render.

I'm just wondering(cause it didn't rendered the layout a few days ago) 
Is there a way to tell rails to render the layout only for html request formats ?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple if ? if condition render json and layout false elsif ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently if you layout file name does not have a .html it'll be used for all request types.. my layout file was x.erb changing it to x.html.erb solves this issue.

Comment: Omg this was fantastic! Clutch

Comment: Omg thank you! For years I couldn't figure out why my app would sometimes render layout for `format.js { ... }`, and sometimes it would not. It turned out one of our layouts was missing the `.html` part in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render 'something.html.erb'}
   format.json { render json: @next_level.to_json ,layout: false}
end
```